# Printing POS receipts through vb .net

Tags: vb.net, printing, microsoft-dynamics, point-of-sale

I am using the Epson TMT88v receipt printer for printing the receipts through Microsoft RMS POS. Now, i am developing a vb.net win application and want to use this printer to print my receipts. The functions were inbuilt with RMS to use the printer.

Can you please suggest which dll I need to utilise this printer in my win app.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [Microsoft POS for .Net SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=5355). The documentation is located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429024.aspx).
 You will also need the [EPSON OPOS ADK for .Net](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=39)

Answer (score 0):

you can find how to do a simple Point of Sale in Visual BAsic .Net

Visit [TyroDeveloper](http://www.tyrodeveloper.com)

[Point Of Sale in Visual Basic .Net](http://www.tyrodeveloper.com/2012/03/point-of-sale-in-visual-basic-part-1.html)